# How to load a trained ML model with pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am very new to Machine Learning, and very lack of the experience. Recently i am trying to collect my own datasets and see the performance of it on a [trained model](https://github.com/Turoad/CLRNet). In README.md it only tells me how to train my own model, but it did not tell me how to load his model direct from [here](https://github.com/turoad/CLRNet/releases).

For instance, i want to try this trained model (culane_r18.pth.zip). How i am suppose to load this model? Should i start a new python file?

```
# What should i add here?
... 

FILE = "culane_r18.pth"

device = torch.device('cpu')
model = Model(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(FILE, map_location=device))

...
```

I have only finished the [pytorch tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c36lUUr864M), and now i do not know what should i do with is current model.

Can anyone give me some help or tell me where should i find more details about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try testing it but personally I'd add another function based on `Runner.validate()` [here](https://github.com/Turoad/CLRNet/blob/7269e9d1c1c650343b6c7febb8e764be538b1aed/clrnet/engine/runner.py#L126) so that you don't need to bother with `cfg`. Maybe like

```
    def predict(self, data):
        self.net.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = self.net(data)
            output = self.net.module.heads.get_lanes(output)
        return output
```

Which you can just call `runner.predict(data)` similar to how `validate()` is called in `main.py` [here](https://github.com/Turoad/CLRNet/blob/7269e9d1c1c650343b6c7febb8e764be538b1aed/clrnet/engine/runner.py#L34).

You should be able to find the appropriate dataset from [here](https://github.com/Turoad/CLRNet/tree/main/clrnet/datasets) and dataloader from [here](https://github.com/Turoad/CLRNet/blob/7269e9d1c1c650343b6c7febb8e764be538b1aed/clrnet/datasets/registry.py#L33).